# 'To take something into account' vs. 'to take something into consideration'

Tags: meaning, word-choice, differences, idioms, writing-style

OALD defines the expressions as follows:

> **to take something into account**: to consider particular facts,
> circumstances, etc. when making a decision about something
>
> **to take something into consideration**: to think about and include a
> particular thing or fact when you are forming an opinion or making a
> decision

While they mean roughly the same thing, the word *consideration* being marked as *formal* leads me to believe that the difference between the two is purely stylistic.

Am I right in thinking that the difference is just a matter of style? Please clarify that one for me.

Comment: The "formal" implication may be nothing more than an acknowledgement that in the UK judicial system at least, the standard phrasing uses the word "consideration". In general parlance they mean the same, and don't represent clearly-distinguished "registers".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it's a matter of style.  One means that you account for something in your decision/judgment; the other means that you consider it during your decision/judgment.  It comes to the same thing.